# Where from is currCount coming in this example?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I watched [Web Dev Simplified](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFbNIlppjAuEX4znoulh0Cw) [video about writing cleaner code in React](https://youtu.be/0yzoAbrjV6k), but this example is even too clean to my understanding, because I can't figure out what mechanism gives value to `currCount`-parameter in arrow-function (which itself is parameter to hook function `setCount`), whole example is [in github](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Noob-Vs-Pro-Code/blob/master/5-react-state-update/src/3-pro/Counter.js), but here I copy actual component-function for context:

```
function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount)

  function incrementCount() {
    setCount(currCount => currCount + 1)
  }

  function decrementCount() {
    setCount(currCount => currCount - 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(count)
  }, [count])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
      {count}
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I need an introduction to `currCount`: where is it initialized with the current count variable (or copy of state?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currCount` is only used in lambdas, which have their own context.

`currCount => currCount` is JS shorthand for

```
function anonymous(currCount) {
  return currCount;
}
```

You can probably see that `currCount` could be called anything because it's closed in the anonymous function's context.

```
function anonymous(iceCream) {
  return iceCream;
}
```

In this case, `setCount` accepts a lambda or a non-function value.
So `setCount(g => g + 1)` is basically equivalent to `setCount(count + 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from here:

```
// let's say we have
const initialCount = 1;

const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
```

After this line you have `setCount` function that you can use to update `count` which at the moment is 1. For instance, you can do `setCount(123)`.

But, what if your new value is not a simple number, like 123, but  something that you need to calculate and moreover it is computed using the previous state or previous count value.

React docs says:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to setCount. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value.

Let's try to do it:

```
// first we need a function to compute new value 
function computeNewCount(prevCount) {
    return prevCount + 1;
}

// second at some point we need to call setCount to do the actual update
// and React will call this function for you and pass previous count value as argument 
setCount(computeNewCount);
```

Usually, we don't write code like this. Instead of writing a function, you can use arrow function, which looks much simpler:

```
// that's our computeNewCount as arrow function
prevCount => prevCount + 1

// and you can pass it to setCount
// React will do the rest (as above)
setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
```